# Sending raw video stream over network to an encoder

Tags: osx, streaming

I'm trying to build a setup using OS X machines for streaming live video. Currently I use Flash Media Live Encoder on the same machine that is handling the video input unfortunately because FMLE uses up a lot of resources it causes delays in the video capture which can sometimes cause a latency of over 10 seconds on the video inputs.

What I would like to do is have FMLE encoding on a remote computer on the network and have something in-between to essentially forward a webcam device from one machine to another without the overhead of it being encoded on the first machine.

I'm not sure if something like this is possible but I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Would an application such as [`motion`](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) do what you need? Take a look at [motion's network camera features](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#Network_Cameras):

- [netcam_http](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#netcam_http)
- [netcam_proxy](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#netcam_proxy)
- [netcam_tolerant_check](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#netcam_tolerant_check)
- [netcam_url](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#netcam_url)
- [netcam_userpass](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideBasicFeatures#netcam_userpass)

Also take a look at [motion's webcam server features](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebcamServer).

> Motion has simple webcam server built in. The video stream is in mjpeg format.

Once you've set it up so that it's streaming a web camera's video stream you can connect to it and display it using `mplayer`:

```
$ mplayer -demuxer lavf http://www.myurl.com:8081/stream.mjpg
```

Comment: Hi Sim, thanks for the lead. I'll test it out and see what I can get.

Comment: @Rory - if you could explain the encoding that FMLE does and also what you're current setup looks like (camera(s) ---> FMLE) I could probably give you more direct help.

Comment: The current setup basically consists of a Canon DSLR -> Camera Live  -> Syphon -> CamTwist -> FMLE. I essentially want to get FMLE off the same machine so it doesn't add high latency to the video capture.

Comment: @Rory - what are Camera Live, Syphon, and CamTwist?

Comment: Camera Live is an application to feed Canon DSLR footage into the Syphon framework which is a framework which allows video sharing between applications on OS X https://code.google.com/p/syphon-implementations/ and CamTwist is basically a software video mixer which I use to feed the camera and other sources into FMLE http://camtwiststudio.com/